# Is there a fast, reasonable way to compute the approximate value of $\log(- \log x)$?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I have a practical application where it would be useful to have a fast way to compute the approximate value of $\log (- \log x)$, for $0 < x < 1$, to maybe two decimal digits of precision.  (This may be inexact, since the range is $-\infty$ to $\infty$.)

Comment: I don't think your function is defined on interval $(0,1)$

Comment: You're right, I omitted the negation of the inner log function.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re working in a language that provides access to the bit representation of floating point values (e.g. Java or C), you can use that to compute approximate logarithms: extract the exponent, multiply it by $\log2$ and add an approximation of the logarithm of the significand by linear interpolation from a table. [Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question2463859.java) that does this with a table size of $1024$ and achieves two-digit precision; you can adjust the table size if you want more precision.

Comment: The question was asked nearly 7 years ago. I think just calling $\log(-\log\,x)$ may well give pretty good performance now.  And maybe it would have done 7 years ago: requests for a fast way of coding something simple should always be accompanied by evidence to show that there is a genuine performance problem with the obvious approach.

Comment: @RobArthan: I got a speed up by about a factor of $2.5$. In contexts where the calls could be inlined, the speed up was even higher. The question was edited just today. If it’s no longer an open question, it should be deleted.

Comment: A factor of 2.5 can be vital, or neither here nor there. However, it's an old question, so I won't make a fuss that the original question doesn't quantify the required performance.

Comment: The commenters are correct.  Indeed, even back when I posted the question, C was a likely implementation language, and I should have considered whether it would suffice to simply extract the 16 bits containing the exponent and the high order part of the faction and looking up the answer from a table of 64k values.